# How to place a ADBannerView outside of UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, iad

I have a application that make use of a UINavigationController. In the rootview I have added a iAd ADBannerView. When the user navigates to another view the ADBannerView moves away. 
So, the idea is that I keep the ADBannerView on the screen.

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the banner as a subview of the window, and then move your navigation controller's view down so it fits below the banner view.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I will try this tonight. Will let you know if I get it to work.

Comment: I figured out that you can't directly add a ADBannerView to the window, but you can when you place it in another view. So I have it working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have it working now. But I'm facing another problem now. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582341/problem-with-adbannerview-in-combination-with-uinavigationcontroller

Comment: It would be a lot better if an example was provided.