# Problem with ADBannerView in combination with UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, iad

I have the following application:

I have 1 window. On that window I add two views. One view is the view of the UINavigationController. This is used to let the user navigate through my application. The other view has a ADBannerView on it. This view is placed on the bottom of the screen.

The user can navigate through my application without any problems and the ADBannerView keeps on the screen to show advertisements. But when the user clicks on the ADBannerView and close it again the banner is moved to the top of the screen and the UINavigationController views are not responding any more.

Anyone has any idea why this happens and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be  a bug in the iAdBanner view implementation. I had the same problem with my own app. When the banner expands to show the full ad, it changes it frame to fill the screen. Then when the ad is dismissed, it doesn't reset the full frame, meaning the ad banner is still occupying the entire screen, but only drawing in a small part of it.

Try implementing `- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner` from the `ADBannerViewDelegate` protocol and adjusting the frame of the ad back to it's original size (usually 320 x 50).

I have raised this as a bug with Apple, but not gotten any response as yet. Feel free to duplicate it.

Comment: That sounds plausible. I will try this fix to tonight and if this workaround works I will raise a bug with Apple. Thanks for the fast response.